# If a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) what type is a?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Si a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

what type is A?

well im trying to learn how to use python but im having a lot of problems, idk if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Try it and find out.

Here's how I got `class numpy.ndarray`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: I replaced your screenshot of text with the text. Please don't post screenshots of text, it is almost always better to post the text itself, [formatted correctly](/help/formatting)